# Invalid argument for FOR EACH loop

Tags: php

I'm getting an error on a for each loop, saying that it get's invalid argument.

```
$bidder = new MuxBidder( $mailer->bidder_id );
$today = $bidder->getTodayBoughtLeads();
$legum = $bidder->getLegum();
$zipInterval = $bidder->getMeta('zip-intervals');
var_dump($bidder->getMeta('zip-intervals'));
$region = $lead->getRegion();
$zip = $lead->getZip();

// If "revisor"
if ( !$legum ) {
    if( $lead->getPrice( $bidder->getId() ) >= $bidder->getMeta( 'min_clips' ) ) {
        foreach ($zipInterval as $interval) {
            if ($interval['from'] <= $zip && $zip <= $interval['to']) {
                // "revisor" just get the lead straight away
                $this->push_lead( $mailer->lead_id, $mailer->bidder_id );
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

// If Legum user ("advokat")
}
```

The error appears with $zipInterval. When I var_dump that variable I have:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
         ["from"]=> string(4) "0000" ["to"]=> string(4) "9999"
    }
}
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
         ["from"]=> string(4) "1000" ["to"]=> string(4) "9999"
    }
}
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
         ["from"]=> string(4) "1000" ["to"]=> string(4) "9999"
    }
}
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
         ["from"]=> string(4) "0000" ["to"]=> string(4) "9999"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
         ["from"]=> string(0) "" ["to"]=> string(0) ""
    }
}
string(0) ""
```

Can anybody see what's wrong with the argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you call this function more than once?  On the last loop you get an empty string returned instead of an array.

try checking if the value is an array before iterating.

```
<?php
if(is_array($zipInterval)){
  foreach($zipInterval as $interval){
     //...
  }
}
```